# Wrapping text onto new line aligned to viewport

Tags: css, word-break

I am attempting to have text wrap onto the next line but instead of wrapping the text directly beneath the first line, have it wrap and begin at the far left of the viewport. Is this possible?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>some text</p>
  <span> / </span>
  <p class="some-long-text">this is an unnecessarily long string that will wrap to the next line on small devices</p>
</div>

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  > { display: flex; }

  .some-long-text {
    word-break: break-word;
    white-space: inherit;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

This is essentially what I'm seeing:

[image]

Comment: change `flex-direction: row` to `flex-direction: column`. You also may need to put the `span` into the first paragraph, unless you want it to be on its own line.

Comment: I don't think what you're asking is possible, because there's no real way to know which parts of the text will be wrap. You could set all of the text to the far-left using absolute positioning, but I don't think it's possible to set only the second line on the far left.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I think this might be what you are looking for.

```css
.some-text {
        display: inline;
      }
      .span-div {
        float: left;
      }
      .slash {
        padding: 0 1rem;
      }
```

```html
<span class="span-div"><p class="some-text">some text</p><span class="slash">/</span></span><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam reprehenderit vel dolores, neque perspiciatis repellendus quasi assumenda, eaque incidunt totam at officiis qui, sunt facere eveniet aliquid optio, officia atque tenetur odit iste expedita. Est officia cum, nisi, voluptatum consequuntur veniam. Suscipit excepturi repellat, adipisci delectus, unde consequatur impedit amet vero voluptates minus voluptatum aut alias, quod. Quaerat doloribus numquam alias veniam fugiat, recusandae debitis ad atque ipsam esse sit nostrum, dignissimos accusamus facere minima reiciendis rem repellendus iusto, nesciunt perferendis sequi. Voluptatum nesciunt enim et explicabo, laudantium optio iusto expedita fugiat dolores, at debitis molestiae autem, eius totam incidunt!</p>
```